# How to replace NA seperately with linear model in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I've looked up some web pages (but their results don't meet my needs):

- [NA replacing with blanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955561/na-replacing-with-blanks;)
- [Replacing "NA" (NA string) with NA inplace data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712526/replacing-na-na-string-with-na-inplace-data-table;)
- [replace <NA> with NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220913/replace-na-with-na).

I want to write a function that could do this:

Say there is a vector `a`.

```
a = c(100000, 137862, NA, NA, NA, 178337, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 295530)
```

First, find the value before and after the single and consecutive `NA`.
In this situation is `137862, NA, NA, NA, 178337` and `178337, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 295530`.

Second, calculate the slope in every part then replace the `NA`.

```
# 137862, NA, NA, NA, 178337
slope_1 = (178337 - 137862)/4

137862 + slope_1*1 # 1st NA replace with 147980.8
137862 + slope_1*2 # 2nd NA replace with 158099.5
137862 + slope_1*3 # 3rd NA replace with 168218.2

# 178337, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 295530

slope_2 = (295530 - 178337)/6

178337 + slope_2*1 # 4th NA replace with 197869.2
178337 + slope_2*2 # 5th NA replace with 217401.3
178337 + slope_2*3 # 6th NA replace with 236933.5
178337 + slope_2*4 # 7th NA replace with 256465.7
178337 + slope_2*5 # 8th NA replace with 275997.8
```

Finally, the expected vector should be this：

```
a_without_NA = c(100000, 137862, 147980.8, 158099.5, 168218.2, 178337, 197869.2, 217401.3, 
                 236933.5, 256465.7, 275997.8, 295530)
```

If single or consecutive NA is in the begining, then it would be keep.

```
# NA at begining
b = c(NA, NA, 1, 3, NA, 5, 7)

# 3, NA, 5
slope_1 = (5-3)/2
3 + slope_1*1 # 3rd NA replace with 4
b_without_NA = c(NA, NA, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7)

# NA at ending
c = c(1, 3, NA, 5, 7, NA, NA)

# 3, NA, 5
slope_1 = (5-3)/2
3 + slope_1*1 # 1st NA replace with 4
c_without_NA = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 7, NA, NA)
```

Note: in my real situation, every element of the vector is increasing(`vector[n + 1] > vector[n]`).

I know the principle, but I don't know how to write a self-define function to implement this.

Any help will highly appreciated!!

Comment: @ akrun, Sorry, it's a mistake, I have updated my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach with `data.table`.  Get the run-length-id (`rleid`) of consecutive NA in 'a' ('grp'), create two temporary columns 'a1', 'a2' as the `lag` and `lead` of 'a', grouped by 'grp', create the 'tmp' based on the calculation and finally `fcoalesce` the original 'a' with that 'tmp'

```
library(data.table)
data.table(a)[, grp := rleid(is.na(a))][, 
  c('a1', 'a2') := .(shift(a), shift(a, type = 'lead'))][, 
   tmp := first(a1) + seq_len(.N) *( (last(a2) - first(a1))/(.N + 1)), 
      .(grp)][, fcoalesce(a, tmp)]
#[1] 100000.0 137862.0 147980.8 158099.5 168218.2 178337.0 
#[7] 197869.2 217401.3 236933.5 256465.7 275997.8 295530.0
```

Comment: I got a new problem. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67427949/how-to-use-none-standard-evaluation-in-r

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I have a new problem, I would appreciate it if you have time to help me look at it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141082/matching-controls-to-cases-using-multiple-conditions-in-r)

Answer (score 5):

`zoo`'s `na.approx` can help :

```
a = c(100000, 137862, NA, NA, NA, 178337, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 295530)
zoo::na.approx(a, na.rm = FALSE)

# [1] 100000.0 137862.0 147980.8 158099.5 168218.2 178337.0 197869.2 217401.3
# [9] 236933.5 256465.7 275997.8 295530.0

b = c(NA, NA, 1, 3, NA, 5, 7)

zoo::na.approx(b, na.rm = FALSE)
#[1] NA NA  1  3  4  5  7

c = c(1, 3, NA, 5, 7, NA, NA)
zoo::na.approx(c, na.rm = FALSE)
#[1]  1  3  4  5  7 NA NA
```

Comment: I got a new problem. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67427949/how-to-use-none-standard-evaluation-in-r

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I have a new problem, I would appreciate it if you have time to help me look at it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141082/matching-controls-to-cases-using-multiple-conditions-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose I defined a custom function:

```
my_replace_na <- function(x) {
  non <- which(!is.na(x))          # Here we extract the indices of non NA values
  
  for(i in 1:(length(non)-1)) {
    if(non[i+1] - non[i] > 1) {
      c <- non[i+1]
      b <- non[i]
      
      for(i in 1:(c - b - 1)) {
        x[b+i] <- x[b]  + ((x[c] - x[b]) / (c - b))*i
      }
    }
  }
  x
}

a <- c(100000, 137862, NA, NA, NA, 178337, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 295530)
my_replace_na(a)

 [1] 100000.0 137862.0 147980.8 158099.5 168218.2 178337.0 197869.2 217401.3 236933.5 256465.7
[11] 275997.8 295530.0

# NA at begining
d <- c(NA, NA, 1, 3, NA, 5, 7)
my_replace_na(d)

[1] NA NA  1  3  4  5  7

# NA at ending
e <- c(1, 3, NA, 5, 7, NA, NA)
my_replace_na(e)

[1]  1  3  4  5  7 NA NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R option using `approx`

```
> approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)], a[!is.na(a)], seq_along(a))$y
 [1] 100000.0 137862.0 147980.8 158099.5 168218.2 178337.0 197869.2 217401.3
 [9] 236933.5 256465.7 275997.8 295530.0
```